# Why was the name "arange" chosen for the numpy function?

Tags: python, numpy, naming-conventions, naming, pep

Is there a specific reason the numpy function [`arange`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.arange.html) was named so?

People [habitually](https://www.google.com/search?q="no+attribute+arrange"+site:stackoverflow.com) make the typo `arrange`, assuming it is spelled as the English word, so the choice seems like something of an oversight given that other less ambiguously spelled options (`range` etc) are unused by numpy.

Was it chosen as a portmanteau of **a**rray and **range**?

Comment: Travis alludes to it in his 2006 book, http://web.mit.edu/dvp/Public/numpybook.pdf,  Quote: "Function similar to Python’s built-in range() function except it returns an ndarray object"

Comment: Shadowing `range` when importing numpy with * would a nuisance.  `sum` and `min` are shadowed, but with fewer issues.  For example, `for i in range(10):` is preferable to `for i in arange(10):`.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

NumPy derives from an older python library called Numeric (in fact, [the first array object built for python](http://www.numpy.org/old_array_packages.html)). The `arange` function dates back to this library, and its etymology is detailed in its manual:

> #### *arrayrange()*
>
> The `arrayrange()` function is similar to the `range()` function in Python, except that it returns an array as opposed to a list.
>
> ...
>
> `arange()` is a shorthand for `arrayrange()`.
>
> - Numeric Manual
>   [2001](http://www.numpy.org/_downloads/numeric-manual.pdf) (p. 18-19), [1999](http://www.lassp.cornell.edu/sethna/DM/Documentation/numpy.pdf) (p.23)

Tellingly, there is another example with `array(range(25))` (p.16), which is functionally the same as `arrayrange()`.

Comment: And `linspace` is for linearly space(vs `geomspace` and `logspace`)?

Answer (score 2):

It is explicitly [modelled on](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=mCrrCAAAQBAJ&pg=PA150&lpg=PA150&dq=python+"arange"+"xrange") the Python `range` function. The precedent for prefixing `a` was that in Python 1 there was already a variant of `range` called `xrange`.

Comment: Though I wouldn't surprised if `arange` preceeds `xrange`.  Any idea when `xrange` was added to Py2?

Comment: @hpaulj, Looking at https://www.python.org/doc/versions/, it seems to have been added in python2.0, in October 2000.

Comment: `xrange` was in Python 1.5.2 (1998). Maybe earlier, but that would have been before my time.

Comment: `xrange` has been in python since at least as far back as 1.4 (25 October 1996) https://docs.python.org/release/1.4/lib/node26.html