# What is the 'a' in numpy.arange?

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-ndarray

What does the 'a' in numpy's `numpy.arange` method stand for, and how does it differ from a simple `range` produced by Python's builtin `range` method (definitionally, not in terms of performance and whatnot)?

I tried looking online for an answer to this, but all I find is tutorials for how to use `numpy.arange` by GeeksForGeeks and co.

Comment: Performance is a big part of it. `range` creates relatively large and expensive python `int` as opposed to `arange` building a contiguous array of hardware level integers.

Comment: But it depends on what you do next. If you want to iterate individual integers, `range` is better. `arange` would create an ndarray but then when you iterate, it would have to build `numpy.intxx` objects for each.

Comment: Think of `arange` as the function name, not as 'a'+'range'; the 'a' is just part of the name.  In Python 2, `range` produced a list; in Py3, it produces a generator like `range` object.  If not used in an iteration, you need `list(range(n))`.  For simple cases like `np.arange(5)`, the result looks much the same, expect it's a numpy array.  The official doc is: https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.arange.html

Comment: The from the suggested duplicate, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55102806/why-was-the-name-arange-chosen-for-the-numpy-function, it looks like I previously found a quote from the `numpy` developer.  In any case, I think it's more important to think of `arange` as a function by itself, rather than as an extension of `range`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why was the name "arange" chosen for the numpy function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55102806/why-was-the-name-arange-chosen-for-the-numpy-function)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can inspect the return types and reason about what it could mean that way:

```
print(type(range(0,5))) 
import numpy as np  
print(type(np.arange(0,5)))
```

Which prints:

```
<class 'range'>
<class 'numpy.ndarray'>
```

Here's a related question: [Why was the name "arange" chosen for the numpy function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55102806/why-was-the-name-arange-chosen-for-the-numpy-function)

1. Some people do `from numpy import *` which would shadow `range` which causes problems.
2. Naming the function `arrayrange` was not chosen because it's too long to type.

Comment: If you think this question is a duplicate, please vote to close it as one.

Comment: Thank you! This is a perfect answer to my question :D!

Answer (score 1):

From the previous SO we learn that the 'a' stands, in some sense, for 'array'.  `arange` is a function that returns a numpy array that is similar, at least in simple cases, to the list produced by `list(range(...))`.  From the official `arange` docs:

> For integer arguments the function is roughly equivalent to the Python built-in range, but returns an ndarray rather than a range instance.

```
In [104]: list(range(-3,10,2))
Out[104]: [-3, -1, 1, 3, 5, 7, 9]

In [105]: np.arange(-3,10,2)
Out[105]: array([-3, -1,  1,  3,  5,  7,  9])
```

In py3, `range` by itself is "unevaluated", it's generator like.  It's the equivalent of the py2 `xrange`.

The best "definition" is the official documentation page:

https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.arange.html

But maybe you are wondering when to use one or the other.   The simple answer is - if you are doing python level iteration, `range` is usually better.  If you need an array, use `arange` (or `np.linspace` as suggested by the docs).

```
In [106]: [x**2 for x in range(5)]
Out[106]: [0, 1, 4, 9, 16]

In [107]: np.arange(5)**2
Out[107]: array([ 0,  1,  4,  9, 16])
```

I often use `arange` to create a example array, as in:

```
In [108]: np.arange(12).reshape(3,4)
Out[108]: 
array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3],
       [ 4,  5,  6,  7],
       [ 8,  9, 10, 11]])
```

While it is possible to make an array from a `range`, e.g. `np.array(range(5))`, that is relatively slow.  `np.fromiter(range(5),int)` is faster, but still not as good as the direct `np.arange`.

Answer (score 0):

The 'a' stands for 'array' in numpy.arange. Numpy.arange is a function that produces an **array of sequential numbers within a given interval**. It differs from Python's builtin range() function in that it can handle floating-point numbers as well as arbitrary step sizes. Also, the output of numpy.arange is an array of elements instead of a range object.